# Pagefactory throwing null in Page Object Structure

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am implementing pagefactory in my Page object model automation framework. My existing framework works fine without pagefactory. Now I am implementing pagefactory to invoke elements. I am facing a issue where Pagefactory element throwing null values.
I have a doubt that it may be because of constructors not sure.

I have build a framework based on Page Object Model
Have packages as below :-
com.automationframework
com.configutaion
com.pageObject
com.testcases
com.testsuites

My testsuites classes invokes testcases present in testcases package and invoke driver and other framework based classes in automationframework. 
I know it's hard to grab the error by simply read few stuff but may anyone faced same issue and can help me.

My Page class looks something like below :-

```
public class SynchronizationPage extends Page {

    ExcelLib xl = new ExcelLib();

    private WebElement element = null;

    public SynchronizationPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    protected boolean isSecured() {
        return true;
    }

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[@class='header-font']/span[@class='icon-cog']")
    @CacheLookup
    public WebElement HoverOnSettings;
}
```

My testcase class :-

```
public class SyncTest extends AutomationTestCaseVerification {

//  SynchronizationPage sync = new SynchronizationPage(Page.driver);
    SignOutPage signout = new SignOutPage(Page.driver);
    ExcelLib xl = new ExcelLib();
    SynchronizationPage synccc = PageFactory.initElements(Page.driver, SynchronizationPage.class);

    private WebElement element = null;
    private WebDriver driver;

    public SyncTest() {
        super();
    }


    @Override
    protected void verifyTestCases() throws Exception {
        syncFeature();
    }

    public void syncFeature() throws Exception {

        try {
         WebDriverWait waits = new WebDriverWait(Page.driver, 60);
    //   waits.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(synccc.clickOnOffButton)).click();
         synccc.clickOnOffButton.click();
         System.out.println("Yes I clicked");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("error ="+ex.getMessage());
            }

    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

I am getting error like below :-

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.click(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.cc.automation.testcases.SyncTest.syncFeature(SyncTest.java:130)
>     at
>   com.cc.automation.testcases.SyncTest.verifyTestCases(SyncTest.java:60)
>     at
>   com.cc.automation.automationframework.AutomationTestCaseVerification.Execute(AutomationTestCaseVerification.java:58)
>     at
>   com.cc.automation.testsuites.SynchronizationTest.testSync(SynchronizationTest.java:22)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

I have also tried to apply below but still not working :-

PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);

[image]

[image]

Comment: instead of printing ex.getMessage() - use ex.printStackTrace() to show error and add it to the topic

Comment: Thanks for response @Vitaliy .. I have added the stacktrace

Comment: Error is in `com.cc.automation.testcases.SyncTest.syncFeature(SyncTest.java:130)`. Which line exactly is that?

Comment: you've got nullPointerException on line `synccc.clickOnOffButton.click();` Stop test in debug on that place and check if `synccc` object is not null , same with `clickOnOffButton`. Where it initialized? Probably `clickOnOffButton` is null.

Comment: @ Vitaliy Moskalyuk - synccc is not null ... I have added a snapshot at the end of the question.

Comment: @Rafał Laskowski - At line 129 and 130 .. below two code are present

   synccc.clickOnOffButton.click();
   System.out.println("Yes I clicked");

Comment: ok, and  clickOnOffButton ? seems it's null =( can you show hot it's initialized? i

Comment: Thats seems fine too . I have added the image of that too just now

Comment: Please provide code with `clickOnOffButton` initialization

Comment: It's a simple webelement function as below :-

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@value='false']")
    @CacheLookup
    public WebElement clickOnOffButton;

Comment: PageObjectPattern returns NULL if object was not found. Are you sure this button was found?

Comment: I believe yes.. Because same script was running fine with my normal script without pagefactory

Comment: in debug purpose try to do in debug "driver.findElement(By.xpath(...)).isDisplayed()" and provide OffButton locator there. I think element is just not found, or you haven't waited enough for it to load

Comment: Why did you comment out `wait.until`? Was it also returning an exception?

Comment: Yes it was also returning the null

Comment: I'm 90% sure `clickOnOffButton` causes NPE.
Please add `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='false']"));` BEFORE line with `click()` and let as know if it throws `NoSuchElementException` or do as @Vitaliy said in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try once by calling `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);` inside the constructor of your SynchronizationPage class.